# Get Integer number from a Float?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I Have a number that is divided by 12 Months.

I need to get the result of the division as an Integer number.

Ex:

```
 mTblDetailMonth.FieldByName('Target_').asfloat := (MTblDetail.FieldByName('Target_').AsInteger / 12 );
```

When the `MTblDetail.FieldByName('Target_').AsInteger` is equal to 20 and divide
 `20 / 12`, the Result is `1.666666667`.

I need to get the number 1 only and then calculate the floating decimal number.

Comment: You could just use div instead of /, it is integer division. Integer result of expression will be converted to float implicitly. Also see: Floor and Ceil functions in math unit.

Comment: What do you think the right answer is? You want a whole number x such that x*12=20?

Comment: Or do you want to split the value into integer and fractional part? What will you do with these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, so here's two alternatives:

The answer to your question as it is written (assuming an integer variable `years` and a float variable `remainder`)
use `trunc` to get the integer part of the division result

```
years := trunc(MTblDetail.FieldByName('Target_').AsInteger / 12); // returns 1
remainder := MTblDetail.FieldByName('Target_').AsInteger / 12 - years; // returns 0.6666...
```

Since you talk about months, maybe you want to know 'years' and 'months' as integers.
If so, use `div` and `mod` operators:

```
years := MTblDetail.FieldByName('Target_').AsInteger div 12 ;  // returns 1
months := MTblDetail.FieldByName('Target_').AsInteger mod 12 ; // returns 8
```

Comment: Excellent Done (Y).Thanks